# How do I determine if an RSS feed is XML or JSON?

Tags: xml, json, rss

Is there a way to tell if a feed is XML, JSON, or both?

Comment: Just a note: a feed can't simultaneously be both valid XML and valid JSON. It would require a custom reader to extract the information for each of the formats from a single document, and if it requires custom reading logic, it's not valid for the format in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and sure-fire way would be simply to run it through a XML and a JSON parser, and see which one works without generating syntax errors. For example, in PHP, try `json_encode($feed_string)` and `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($feed_string);`

Alternatively, you can just do some simple string checking. All properly-formed XML documents start with `<?xml`, while JSON typically starts with `{` since the feed data is a Javascript object.

The samples Google provides as the two feed formats may be helpful:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html

Comment: Although it's a good idea to include it, the XML declaration is not guaranteed to be present in a well-formed XML file. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd and note that an XML declaration is SHOULD instead of MUST.

Comment: Also, proper JSON can start with an array `[ ... ]` as well as an object `{ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really clear on what you mean by 'feed', but if the mime type of a file is set to `application/json`, then it is JSON. XML has two standard mime types (`application/xml` and `text/xml`).

If you don't have access to the mime types (or they are ambiguous), you can check for `<?xml` at the start of a proper xml file. And if that isn't there, then you can probably do a pretty good guess that it is XML if it starts with just `<` and JSON if it starts with `{`. But there is no guarantee they will be correctly formed.

Comment: sorry rodeoclown but i forgot to add RSS feed in the body. my impressions were XML and JSON were the two main standards for delivering RSS

Comment: No worries. RSS is XML by definition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246577/can-i-serve-rss-in-json for some other people who have used JSON to create an RSS-like feed.